# AWS CLI command to execute the API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am trying to execute API gateway using AWS CLI in EC2 instance. I did not find any command in AWS CLI documentation.
Has anyone used CLI before to execute API gateway endpoint?

Thank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, **there is no** such API call in CLI or SDK. You have to use **external tools** to invoke your API.

Examples are, `curl`, `postman` or `requests` package in python.

For example, if you **protect your API through** `aws_iam` you can use [AWSRequestsAuth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) in python to construct valid AWS IAM request. In `postman` you can also provide IAM credentials for the request to such API.

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible with AWS CLI version 2.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/test-invoke-method.html

Here's an example test POST using a file as the request body:

```
aws --region us-west-2 apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id abcd1234 --resource-id abcd12 --http-method POST --path-with-query-string '/records/create' --body file://test-body.json
```

Comment: This should be updated as the new answer

Comment: I am curious as to why the CLI/API documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_TestInvokeMethod.html calls this "Simulate the invocation of a Method in your RestApi with headers, parameters, and an incoming request body." How is it "simulating" the invocation? Isn't it actually invoking it?